# Pressure formula

Tags: pressure

I have recently been studying pressure and the basic pressure formula:

$\ P= F\ /A$

and I was wondering why it does not include direction of the force in the formula and I played around with it for a bit and I got the formula:

$\  P= F\sin( \theta)\ /A$

(not including calculus or varying pressure or area for now). Is this formula correct?

And if so how could I change it to account for a change in area or force?

For example here 30 degrees is theta and the hypotenuse is 10N

[image]

Comment: I think pressure is equal to perpendicular component of the force divided by the area.

Comment: yes sin(theta) would give you the perpendicular value of the force if you take the value of the force as the hypotenuse.

Comment: Please specify with which (vertical or horizontal) the force makes an angle of $\theta$ in your question.

Comment: I edited the question to include an example

Comment: Yes your equation is correct.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure#Definition):
Pressure is the amount of force applied **at right angles** to the surface of an object per unit area.

So your formula including sin(θ) is correct.

Comment: What about this **And if so how could I change it to account for a change in area or force?** ?

Comment: Pressure is an instantaneous magnitude, i.e. if the force or the area change, the pressure at each instant is the value of F/A at that precise instant. If these are functions of time, then P(t) = F(t)/A(t).

Comment: Well that's really what I wrote in my comment but OP didn't reply therefore I deleted it and asked him [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529838/pressure-formula/529845?noredirect=1#comment1197932_529838)

Comment: Sorry I had logged off my computer by that time and i didn't see your comment.